# Customize Backbone.Model creation

Tags: backbone.js, model, constructor, prototype

How can I extend `Backbone.Model`:

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ ... });
```

so that writing

```
model = new MyModel(object)
```

returns `object` itself in case it is already a model,
and creates new Backbone Model otherwise?

I have a custom function `isModel(object)` to check if `object` is a Model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a simple class method would be less confusing that trying to change the way Backbone constructor functions work. The properties second object argument to [`extend`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-extend) get added as properties right on the constructor function so you could do something like this:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // Standard model stuff goes here...
}, {
    toMyModel: function(object) {
        if(isModel(object))
            return object;
        return new MyModel(object);
    }
});
```

And then later:

```
var o = MyModel.toMyModel(someObject);
```

and if `someObject` is already a `MyModel`, you'd get `o === someObject`, otherwise you'd get `new MyModel(someObject)` in `o`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/h38Ks/

---

If you're worried about saying things like:

```
new MyCollection([ myModel, someObject ])
```

then there's nothing to worry about, Backbone will check things for you. I don't see any documented guarantee of this behavior but:

1. The collection knows what sort of models it is supposed to contain (via its [`model`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model) property) so it makes sense that it would do a quick `instanceof` check.
2. If you trace through the code, you'll see that the [collection constructor](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.1.0/backbone.js#L595) calls [`reset`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.1.0/backbone.js#L757) which calls [`add`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.1.0/backbone.js#L631) which calls [`set`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.1.0/backbone.js#L662) which calls [`_prepareModel`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.1.0/backbone.js#L906) to convert objects to model instances; you'll find an `instanceof` check right at the top of `_prepareModel`.

Note that `_prepareModel` will accept any `Backbone.Model` instance, not just instances of the collection's `model`. This shouldn't be a problem unless your code is really confused.

You can see this "is it already a model?" stuff in action right here: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/YCdV7/

Comment: Thanks, good idea, the only thing is my model creation is done by passing an array to a Collection constructor, so I would have to rewrite the latter, which is again the same problem

Comment: Are you sure that the collection won't do that check for you? A cursory check of the source suggests that it might. I'm on my tablet at the moment but I can check further in the morning.

Comment: Seems you are right. Didn't think about that, things can be easier than they look :)

Comment: I just did a run through the Backbone code to find the "is this thing a model already?" check.

Comment: Yeah, I could see it. It is a bit counter-intuitive that Model and Collections work differently here. IMO if `model` is already a Model, there is no reason for `new Backbone.Model(model)` to create a messy new model as it currently does.